# parent is extending beyond the screen as child count increases

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
`;
```

```
<Container>
 {[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map((element, index) => {
                      return (
                    <Child key={element}>{/*some random code*/}</Child>
                      );
                    })}
</Container>
```

```
const Child = styled.div`
  padding: 2%;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 77px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  margin: 1%;

  border-radius: 12px;
`;
```

the above code in styled component and reactjs is causing parent to extend so the whole code containing parent component overflows the screen can anyone give me the reason why ??

and styled is component imported from styled components package in reactjs

So this is what I want : first the area should be vertically scrollable and then the content inside it should be horizontally scrollable and also both parent and child should have height and width dependent on their parent and when the whole UI is made up they should not extend beyond the screen size as the main container that contains the both containers have been given width 100vw and height 100vh.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flex-wrap: wrap;` instead of `flex-wrap: nowrap;`

Using **nowrap** tells the flex items to be laid out in a single line and allows the flex container to overflow. Using **wrap** will allow the items to go onto a new line before overflowing.

Comment: I need the scroller and all content in one row

Comment: Oh, then you probably want to set the `max-width` of the parent container to something other than 100%. You could try `100vw` for the screen width, or something like `500px` for a set width. If that helps, I can update my answer!

Comment: i dont want fixed width 'cause i want container to be responsive

Comment: more like flexible

Comment: @streak you are going to have to more clearly explain what you want then. You've said a lot of things you don't want, but never explained the behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I explained it in question now